# Node.js giving empty array for dependent queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, ionic-framework

I have PHP website in which, chat module is working fine ( via ajax ).
Now I am creating Ionic app for this chat module, So I am trying to convert my PHP code on NODE.js

To get a list of chat users i wrote this code in helper.js file

```
setMessage:function(message1){
    message=message1;
},
setPeople:function(id,people1){
    people[id]=people1;
},
setChatlist:function(data9){
    chatlist.push(data9);
},

setRecorder:function(data8){
    recorder.push(data8);
},

getUserChatList:function(uid,connection,callback){
    chatlist=[];
    recorder=[];
    people=[];
    message={};     
    var data={
        query:"select id from messages where recipient_id='"+uid+"' or  timeline_id='"+uid+"' order by timestamp desc ",
        connection:connection
    }

    var db_conncetion=data.connection;
    var query=data.query;
    var insert_data=data.insert_data;

    db_conncetion.getConnection(function(err,con){
        if(err){
          con.release();
        }else{
            con.query(String(query),insert_data,function(err,rows){

            if(!err) {
            if(rows.length>0){
                query1="select DISTINCT recipient_id from messages where timeline_id='"+uid+"' order by timestamp desc ";
                con.query(String(query1),insert_data,function(err1,rows1){
                        rows1.forEach(function(element1, index1, array1){       
                            var receiverId=element1.recipient_id;
                            var receiverSql = "SELECT time,text FROM messages WHERE timeline_id=" +uid+ " AND recipient_id="  +receiverId+" ORDER BY time DESC";                        
                            con.query(String(receiverSql),insert_data,function(err2,rows2){
                                rows2.forEach(function(element2, index2, array2){
                                    people[receiverId]=element2.time;
                                    message[receiverId]=element2.text;
                                });
                                self.setMessage(message);
                                self.setPeople(people,people);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                            var senderIdSql = "SELECT DISTINCT timeline_id FROM messages WHERE recipient_id=" +uid+ " ORDER BY time DESC";                              
                con.query(String(senderIdSql),insert_data,function(err3,rows3){
                        rows3.forEach(function(element1, index1, array1){       
                                var senderId=element1.timeline_id;
                                var senderSql = "SELECT time,text FROM messages WHERE recipient_id=" +uid+  " AND timeline_id=" +senderId+ " ORDER BY time DESC";
                                con.query(String(senderSql),insert_data,function(err2,rows2){
                                    rows2.forEach(function(element2, index2, array2){
                                        if (!self.isset(people[senderId]) || element2.time > people[senderId])
                                        people[senderId]=element2.time;
                                        message[senderId]=element2.text;
                                    self.setPeople(senderId,element2.time); 
                                    self.setMessage(message);
                                }); 
                                });
                            });
                    });

                }   
                Object.keys(people).forEach(function (key){
                 var tempArray={};
                 tempArray['id']=key;
                 tempArray['text']=message[key];
                self.setRecorder(tempArray);
                });

        recorder.forEach(function (key){
            var user_query="SELECT * FROM  accounts WHERE id=" +key +" AND active=1 ";
                con.query(String(user_query),insert_data,function(err3,rows3){
                    var tmp1=[];
                    rows3.forEach(function(element2, index2, array2){
                        var data1={};
                        data1['receiver_id']=element2.id;
                        data1['receiver_username']=element2.username;
                        data1['receiver_name']=element2.name;
                        data1['receiver_thumbnail_url']=element2.thumbnail_url;
                        data1['receiver_online']=0;
                            data1['receiver_message'] = recorder[key];
                        tmp1.push(data1);

                    });
                self.setChatlist(tmp1);     
                });                             

        });
                var ret_data={};
                ret_data['status']=200;
                ret_data['success']=1;
                ret_data['messages']=chatlist;
                console.log(ret_data);
                console.log("1111");
                callback(ret_data);
                con.release();
            //console.log(message);

            } else {
              console.log(err);  
              console.log("Query failed");  
            }        
          });
        }
    });

 }
```

But when i am calling this method via socket it's giving an empty array

listening in http://localhost:3000
{ status: 200, success: 1, messages: [] }
1111

Please tell why it's giving an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be an empty array according to your current code.

All the db calls will be asynchronous and will not wait for its completion. It will execute the next line which will execute the following code before the db calls get finished:

```
 var ret_data = {};
      ret_data['status'] = 200;
      ret_data['success'] = 1;
      ret_data['messages'] = chatlist;
      console.log(ret_data);
      console.log("1111");
      callback(ret_data);
      con.release();
      //console.log(message);
```

So your callback gets executed with initial value that is `[]` and thus you have the value as `[]`.

You have to manage the db calls and the data to be sent. You can use promises or async/await to this. The code will be much more clean and traceable. Take a good look at them.

Comment: But I am also using self.setPeople and self.setMessage for callBack

Comment: But the callback function will get executed before the functions self.setPeople and self.setMessage will be called.

Comment: I am trying to use Async/Await, as given in example https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait

But its not working. Can you please help me in this?